# How to fix segmentation fault in this code?

Tags: c, matrix

I am very sorry if this is too dumb, but I'm just starting with c and coding in general. I am also sorry this is in spanish, I hope it's not too confusing.
I'm trying to code a board game by using a matrix, and at this point I just want to be able to print the board.
I tried using Eclipse but kept getting errors like error with command-gdb version. I also attempted running it on online C compilers with no success (in this case I get segmentation error).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char *tablero[9][9];
char Rey = 'R';
char gralOro = 'O';
char gralPlata = 'P';
char caballos = 'C';
char lanceros = 'L';
char alfil = 'A';
char torre = 'T';
char peones = 'p';
char vacio = ' ';
char *piezasNegrasPerdidas[20];
char *piezasBlancasPerdidas[20];
void initBoard(){
    for(int i = 0; i<0; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<9; j++){
            if(i==2 || i==6){
                tablero[i][j] = &peones;
                }
            else if(i==3 || i==4 || i==5){
                tablero[i][j]=&vacio;
            }
        }
    }
    tablero[0][0] = &lanceros;
    tablero[0][1] = &caballos;
    tablero[0][2] = &gralPlata;
    tablero[0][3] = &gralOro;
    tablero[0][4] = &Rey;
    tablero[0][5] = &gralOro;
    tablero[0][6] = &gralPlata;
    tablero[0][7] = &caballos;
    tablero[0][8] = &lanceros;
    tablero[1][1] = &alfil;
    tablero[1][7] = &torre;


    tablero[8][0] = &lanceros;
    tablero[8][1] = &caballos;
    tablero[8][2] = &gralPlata;
    tablero[8][3] = &gralOro;
    tablero[8][4] = &Rey;
    tablero[8][5] = &gralOro;
    tablero[8][6] = &gralPlata;
    tablero[8][7] = &caballos;
    tablero[8][8] = &lanceros;
    tablero[7][1] = &alfil;
    tablero[7][7] = &torre;

}
void printTablero(){
    for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c<9; c++){
            printf("[%c]", *(tablero[r][c]));
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
}
int main(){
    printTablero();
    return 0;
}
```

I expect to be able to run this code but I'm a bit clueless on what might be wrong even after doing some research.

Comment: All those pointers to 2D arrays should be 2D arrays: `char *tablero[9][9];` --> `char tablero[9][9];` , in consequence don't dereference when assigning: `tablero[i][j] = &peones;` --> `tablero[i][j] = peones;`. Another issue is that a chess board is 8x8 not 9x9, the check should be `for(int j = 0; j<8; j++){`. And why are you checking from 0 to 0 here: `for(int i = 0; i<0; i++){`

Comment: line 16: weird loop init `for(int i = 0; i<0; i++){`, it will never be executed

Comment: You also forget to call `initBoard` before `printTablero()`

Comment: Oh sorry it should be i<9. But it still won't run. This is for a game called shogi that uses a 9x9 board

Answer (score 1):

Although it could be done this way with a 2D array of pointers pointing to the chars, I wouldn't recommend it. Instead, just have a 2D array of chars:

```
char tablero[9][9]; // without the *
```

Then change the initialization like this:

```
tablero[0][0] = lanceros; // without the &
```

And the prints to this:

```
printf("[%c]", tablero[r][c]);
```

Also, your `for (int i = 0; i < 0; i++)` loop never runs. Change it to instead initialize all the fields correctly. I assume you want a nested loop that sets all of the field to `vacio` here. Furthermore, you're not calling `initBoard` anywhere. I guess it was intended to be called in `main` before calling `printTablero`.

---

In the end, the segmentation fault happened because you're trying to dereference a pointer that wasn't initialized when you printed the array (as `initBoard` isn't called, nothing is initialized), leading to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't make init for every cell of whole board. You need just initialize them with i.e. `vacio`, and after that set smth another to cells.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char * tablero[9][9];
char Rey = 'R';
char gralOro = 'O';
char gralPlata = 'P';
char caballos = 'C';
char lanceros = 'L';
char alfil = 'A';
char torre = 'T';
char peones = 'p';
char vacio = ' ';
char *piezasNegrasPerdidas[20];
char *piezasBlancasPerdidas[20];
void initBoard(){

    for(int i = 0; i<9; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<9; j++){
            if(i==2 || i==6){
                tablero[i][j] = &peones;
                }
            else {
                tablero[i][j]=&vacio;
            }
        }
    }
    tablero[0][0] = &lanceros;
    tablero[0][1] = &caballos;
    tablero[0][2] = &gralPlata;
    tablero[0][3] = &gralOro;
    tablero[0][4] = &Rey;
    tablero[0][5] = &gralOro;
    tablero[0][6] = &gralPlata;
    tablero[0][7] = &caballos;
    tablero[0][8] = &lanceros;
    tablero[1][1] = &alfil;
    tablero[1][7] = &torre;


    tablero[8][0] = &lanceros;
    tablero[8][1] = &caballos;
    tablero[8][2] = &gralPlata;
    tablero[8][3] = &gralOro;
    tablero[8][4] = &Rey;
    tablero[8][5] = &gralOro;
    tablero[8][6] = &gralPlata;
    tablero[8][7] = &caballos;
    tablero[8][8] = &lanceros;
    tablero[7][1] = &alfil;
    tablero[7][7] = &torre;

}
void printTablero(){
    for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c<9; c++){
            printf("[%c]", *(tablero[r][c]));
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
}
int main(){
    initBoard();
    printTablero();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
[L][C][P][O][R][O][P][C][L]
[ ][A][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][T][ ]
[p][p][p][p][p][p][p][p][p]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[p][p][p][p][p][p][p][p][p]
[ ][A][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][T][ ]
[L][C][P][O][R][O][P][C][L]
```